# mysql join to list item from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, join

I am having two tables table_purchase1 and table_purchase2. From these tables i want to list purchase history with order by date.

My tables

```
table_purchase1

purchase_id   user_id    item    date
  1               1       AA1    2011-06-10  
  2               1       AA2    2011-06-12


table_purchase2

purchase_id   user_id    item      date
  1               1       BB1    2011-06-11  
  2               1       BB2    2011-06-13
```

Expecting result

item

```
BB2,AA2,BB1,AA1
```

How can i do this

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use UNION:

```
(SELECT item, `date` FROM table_purchase1)
UNION
(SELECT item, `date` FROM table_purchase2)
ORDER BY `date`
```

If you need single row following *might* work:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
(  (SELECT item, `date` FROM table_purchase1)
 UNION
  (SELECT item, `date` FROM table_purchase2)
 ORDER BY `date`
))
```

Comment: @gowri: I guess you should run a separate query for that, or modify it so that the union part will be in from clause (dont forget mysql requires rename for that) and you can use GROUP_CONCAT(item), COUNT(*)

Answer (score 0):

```
(SELECT
item
FROM
table_purchase1)
UNION
(SELECT
item
FROM
table_purchase2)
ORDER BY `date`
```

Answer (score 0):

$sql = (SELECT `item`, `date` FROM `table_purchase1`) UNION (SELECT `item`, `date` FROM `table_purchase2`) ORDER BY `date`